# Updating the TableViewCell on swift iOS with a message

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, viewcontroller

this is what I have in my view controller. pretty simple, theres a send button and a message field with constraints and table view.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

public let identifier = "ViewController"

private let tableView: UITableView = {
    let table = UITableView()
    table.register(SecureTextViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: SecureTextViewCell.identifier)
    return table
    
}()


private let secureButton : UIButton = {
    let button = UIButton()
    button.setTitle("Secure", for: .normal)
    button.backgroundColor = .link
    button.setTitleColor(.white, for: .normal)
    button.layer.cornerRadius = 12
    button.titleLabel?.font = .systemFont(ofSize: 20, weight: .bold)
    button.layer.masksToBounds = true
    button.addTarget( self, action: #selector(securebuttonTapped), for: .touchUpInside)
    return button
    
}()


let sendButton : UIButton = {
    let button = UIButton()
    button.setTitle("Send", for: .normal)
    button.backgroundColor = .green
    button.setTitleColor(.white, for: .normal)
    button.layer.cornerRadius = 12
    button.titleLabel?.font = .systemFont(ofSize: 20, weight: .bold)
    button.layer.masksToBounds = true
    button.addTarget( self, action: #selector(sendButtonTapped), for: .touchUpInside)
    return button
}()

let textView : UITextField = {
    let text = UITextField()
    text.isHidden = true
    text.isSecureTextEntry = true
    text.backgroundColor = .red
    text.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
    return text
}()

private let messageField: UITextField = {
    let field = UITextField()
    field.autocapitalizationType = .none
    field.autocorrectionType = .no
    field.returnKeyType = .done
    field.layer.cornerRadius = 12
    field.layer.borderWidth = 1
    field.layer.borderColor = UIColor.lightGray.cgColor
    field.placeholder = "Secure Text Message"
    field.leftViewMode = .always
    field.backgroundColor = .white
    field.isOpaque = true
    field.clearButtonMode = .always
    return field
}()
var passwordFieldConstraints : NSLayoutConstraint!
var sendButtonFieldCoonstraints: NSLayoutConstraint!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    
    tableView.delegate = self
    tableView.dataSource = self
    view.addSubview(tableView)
    view.addSubview(messageField)
    view.addSubview(sendButton)
    
    messageField.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    sendButton.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    messageField.addTarget(self, action: #selector(buttonAction), for: .touchUpInside)
    sendButton.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 40).isActive = true
    sendButton.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: tableView.widthAnchor).isActive = true
    

    messageField.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 40).isActive = true
    messageField.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: tableView.widthAnchor).isActive = true
}

override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()

    tableView.frame = view.bounds
    textView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 300, width: view.width, height: 30)
}

@objc func sendButtonTapped() {
    
    print("send button tapped")
}


}


extension ViewController: UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    
    return 5
 }
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) ->           UITableViewCell {
    let text = messageField.text!
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: TextViewCell.identifier, for: indexPath) as! TextViewCell
    cell.configure(with: text)
    return cell
    
}
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return 80
}
}
```

this is my tableViewCell which should get updated with the text I had on my message field?

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

class TextViewCell: UITableViewCell {

static let identifier = "SecureTextViewCell"


let secureText : UITextField = {
    let secureText = UITextField()
    secureText.text = ""
    secureText.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
    secureText.backgroundColor = .link
    return secureText
}()

override init(style: UITableViewCell.CellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
    super .init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
    
    contentView.addSubview(secureText)
}

required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}

override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()
    contentView.addSubview(secureText)
    secureText.frame = CGRect(x: 0,
                                 y: 0,
                                 width: contentView.width,
                                 height: contentView.height)
}

public func configure(with model: String) {
    self.secureText.text = model
    
}
}
```

when I hit the send button I want my cell to update and show the message I send.
I don't know what do put in my send button func or do I go about this in a different way.

ive tried a few this with the send button tapped. on the table view cellForRowAt Ive tried things too.

Im sorry for asking what probably is a simple thing to most coders. im new.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you shouldn't add your text field to cell subviews in the `layoutSubviews` as it's called each time the cell's layout update is needed. According to the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622482-layoutsubviews) you should only place there code to update layout of subviews which can't update automatically:

> Subclasses can override this method as needed to perform more precise
> layout of their subviews. You should override this method only if the
> autoresizing and constraint-based behaviors of the subviews do not
> offer the behavior you want. You can use your implementation to set
> the frame rectangles of your subviews directly.

So update `layoutSubviews` function in your cell to this:

```
override func layoutSubviews() {
   super.layoutSubviews()
   secureText.frame = contentView.bounds
}
```

Now to change the cell's text from the view controller may be as simple as this:

```
@objc func sendButtonTapped() {
    tableView.reloadData()
}
```

This will reload all visible cells of your table and because you already setup text configuration in your `tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell` every cell will display the text of your messageField.

In case you want to update only one specific cell you will need to change your cells configuration logic and then call reload for an exact cell:

```
@objc func sendButtonTapped() {
    let indexPath = IndexPath(row: 0, section: 0) //index of cell to reload
    tableView.reloadRows(at: [indexPath], with: .automatic)
}
```